# Why doesn't this return the tuple and instead returns nonetype?

Tags: python-3.8

Why doesn't this return the tuple and instead returns nonetype? I've tried removing everything I could think of to get it to return the tuple. I either have mistyped something which i have spent an hour or so checking, or i am missing something bigger..
Thanks!!

```
import time

def BONGO_BONGO(item, num=1, wait_time=4):
    time.sleep(.99)
    list_of_positions = []
    if item in list_of_positions:
        result = (1, 333)
        return result

    elif num >= wait_time:
        print(str(wait_time) + " seconds have passed.. ")
        print("test")
        result = (2, 9)
        print(result)
        return result

    else:
        print(str(item) + " execution checked: " + str(num))
        num += 1
        BONGO_BONGO(item=item, num=num)

y = BONGO_BONGO("ITEM444")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay the answer is that the nested bongo_bongo function under the "else" is the function that in the end will return the desired tuple from the "elif". So you need to return that last bongo_bongo function under the "else".

```
import time

def BONGO_BONGO(item, num=1, wait_time=4):
    time.sleep(.99)
    list_of_positions = []
    if item in list_of_positions:
        result = (1, 333)
        return result

    elif num >= wait_time:
        print(str(wait_time) + " seconds have passed.. ")
        print("test")
        result = (2, 9)
        print(result)
        return result

    else:
        print(str(item) + " execution checked: " + str(num))
        num += 1
        result = BONGO_BONGO(item=item, num=num)
        return result

y = BONGO_BONGO("ITEM444")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Y=", y)
```